# How to implement Incremental Authorization with Google API?

Tags: .net, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-oauth

I have an installed app that is a toolkit for the user, and as such they're able to choose their own scopes. I've run in to an issue with a scope limit when being passed as parameters via the URL. As such I'm looking to implement [Incremental Authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp) so that they only have to authorize scopes as they use them, and they don't have to also add scopes again from previous to overwrite.

I'm using the [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.2/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker) class to do the authorization, but I'm not seeing anything that would allow me to implement Incremental Authorization without basically having to rewrite the delivered API classes. Is there any way to do this with the API?

Comment: The library currently doesn't support it. Our code base is in GitHub - https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client. You can create a feature request in the repository, and it will be great if you create a pull request and add this feature yourself. I would recommend you in this point to create a service with all the required scopes from the first place. Another option is to create another service with new scopes. It's not the best solution, but it should work for you.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. I'm working on a pull request now, trying to figure it out without breaking interface contracts and trying to figure out how to test it with my own code. Since I'm creating a wrapper for any/all APIs, I have to let users choose as many scopes as they want, and since they get added to the URL when authorizing they get cut off at something like 1024 characters (30+ scopes). Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks for working on it. Discussion was moved to https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/pull/624 (squid808's pull request)